# How to check the moveit is ready for planning through API

Tags: robotic-arm, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Before I run the manipulator motion node, I need to wait for the moveit to load completely, the load completed sign is shown in the output of the terminal:

```
********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

ros.moveit_ros_move_group: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
ros.moveit_ros_move_group: MoveGroup context initialization complete

You can start planning now!
```

Is there an API through which I can check whether the moveit load completely?  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355886/how-to-check-the-moveit-is-ready-for-planning-through-api/) by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2020-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-26**:
Please do not post screenshots of terminals. It's all text, so copy-paste the text from the terminal into your question.

If/when you fix this, we can re-open your question. Do not post a new one, *edit* your current question to replace the screenshot. Use the `edit` button/link for this.

**Comment by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on 2020-06-26**:
Thank you, I have modified my question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do you feel the need to wait for `move_group` to initialize **everything**?

Usually you should only need to wait for the respective ROS interface you want to use to come up.
E.g., `MoveGroupInterface` proceeds that way:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/b8b57846650f7662a44106e0b7728e0c9ca36888/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L151

If you really want to wait for the `You can start planning now!` message, you will have to either

1. modify move_group around [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/move_group/src/move_group.cpp#L220) to publish to a latched topic, e.g., `move_group/initialized` or
2. write a new MoveGroupCapability that polls `MoveGroupContext::status()` and publishes said topic if it returns true.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2020-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on 2020-06-27**:
@v4hn Thanks for your answer. You are right, `MoveGroupInterface` will wait for the interface to come up. I don't need to program myself to realize the wait function.